# How is TF2 supposed to be set up for an Ackerman steering robot with Navigation2

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am currently working with a physical, ackermann steering robot (car like). Right now my TF is setup with base_link on the ground between the two rear wheels.
However, I notice strange behavior with navigation2, including trying to steer but not move.
I then wondered whether my tf is setup correctly, maybe I need to give navigation 2 a link at the center of my robot, or between the two front wheels ? I didn't find anything online so I think it would be great to have something detailed on it.
In navigation2 I use a MPPI controller with Reeds_Shepp motion model, the path seems to be correctly generated and every link in the parameters is setup to base_link.
Also, base_link is setup as X forward,Y on the left and Z up, and I work on Humble.
I hope someone will be able to help me, tell me if you need more info and I'll try to give them as fast as possible !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417706/how-is-tf2-supposed-to-be-set-up-for-an-ackerman-steering-robot-with-navigation2/) by [Timothée](https://answers.ros.org/users/148408/timoth%C3%A9e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2023-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The coordinate frames for mobile platforms are defined in [REP 105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) including `base_link`. Which you appear to be following correctly. The most common location on ackermann vehicles is the center of the rear axle.

I don't think that the problem that you're having is related to your coordinate frames.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2023-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Timothée](https://answers.ros.org/users/148408/timoth%C3%A9e/) on 2023-07-31**:
You are perfectly right, my problem was a combination of bad settings for my controller, and my node controlling the wheels not turning at the right speed so my robot could not follow the path. Now it does work well, without any changes in the tf tree.